# C# - Read Write Process Memory , Pointers and Offsets Gamer Server Management Tool

Tags: c#, pointers, offset, readprocessmemory

I am coding a **server manager** for a game and got stuck in pointers and offsets in C#. Old server manager is written in vb6 and for some reason does not work on my windows so i decided to code some basic functions of it in C#.

I have pointer and offsets values of everything that is necessary for now i am writing only to get all player names.

Player pointer  = **96C290**    Player name Offset = **+20**

Offset of **+668** give me the next player pointer, and adding **+20** to next player should give me next **player name** and so on.

Reading First Player Name

```
  public static IntPtr BASE_ADDR = new IntPtr(0x96C290);
  public static IntPtr OFFSET_NAME = new IntPtr(0x20);
  const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

  public static void Read()
  {

        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("gameprocessname")[0];
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);   

        //defining data structures
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

        //Reading Base Address pointer value
        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle,(int)BASE_ADDR, buffer, 4, ref bytesRead);
        IntPtr myBaseAddress = new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0));

        //Adding offset of 20 to original base pointer address
        IntPtr namePointer = BASE_ADDR;
        namePointer = IntPtr.Add(namePointer,(int)OFFSET_NAME);


        //Getting memory address of name pointer
        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, (int)namePointer,buffer, 4, ref bytesRead);
        IntPtr playerNameAddress = new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0));


        //reading name from name address . ASCII and Unicode
        byte[] playerNameBuffer = new byte[256];
         ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, (int)playerNameAddress, buffer, 256, ref bytesRead);
        string name = Encoding.Default.GetString(playerNameBuffer);
        MessageBox.Show(name);


        }
```

I am not getting player name . The scripts written in **VB6** are operational.
I am Using **Win8.1 64bit** and the game is very old 32 bit application.

What could be the problem ? i used **cheat engine** to view values manually but it also shows me nothing. Pointer and Offset values are correct.

I have used different offsets values but got none of them return the right values.

The questions is **If i am doing something wrong on coding end ? or it is the OS 64bit issue. **

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the program (because I don't have/know the game) but I see that you read myBaseAddress then you don't use it, may be the problem is in the following lines

```
IntPtr namePointer = BASE_ADDR;
namePointer = IntPtr.Add(namePointer,(int)OFFSET_NAME);
```

that should be

```
IntPtr namePointer = myBaseAddress ;
namePointer = IntPtr.Add(namePointer,(int)OFFSET_NAME);
```